# Unable to perform helm repo update. Getting "(400) when calling the HeadObject operation: Bad Request" error

Tags: kubernetes, amazon-s3, kubernetes-helm

I have few repos in the

```
help repo list
```

but one of them gives this error when I perform

```
helm repo update
```

There was a reported bug in 2020 but that has ben fixed as per this [Github issue](https://github.com/boto/botocore/issues/1413).

Also, the version of my helm is latest

```
version.BuildInfo{Version:"v3.11.0-rc.2", GitCommit:"472c5736ab01133de504a826bd9ee12cbe4e7904", GitTreeState:"clean", GoVersion:"go1.18.9"}
```

```
Hang tight while we grab the latest from your chart repositories...
fatal error: An error occurred (400) when calling the HeadObject operation: Bad Request
```

Any suggestions or comments are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using AWS cli then try to upgrade it to the latest version

Comment: I updated AWS cli... then checked... but when I downgraded help to 3.10.3... it works

Comment: so it's maybe a bug issue in the helm 3.11.0 version

Answer (score 0):

I think this issue has come back in 3.11.0, I am not facing this in 3.10.3